# Can't understand how to sum items price in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello I want to make simple shopping cart.
I am a  beginner in programming. So please help.
I have items with prices and i want to sum up them (quantity equals to one).

veiw

`<h1>Summ:<%= @items.total %></h1>`

model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  def total
      summ = 0
      @items.each do |item|
          summ += item.price
      end
  end

end
```

What is wrong. I have this error NoMethodError in Items#index

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rails defines an `Enumerable::sum` method that you can call. So your view can look like this:

```
<h1>Summ: <%= @items.sum(&:price) %></h1>
```

You could also add a `total` method to your `Order` (or whatever model you are using that has_many :items). Something along the lines of:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  def total
    items.sum(&:price)
  end
end
```

And then your view:

```
<h1><%= @order.total %></h1>
```

Comment: I think the second option is the better path, it is more clear to someone reading your code what you're expecting to show up there.

Answer (score 1):

The instance variable `@items` you are referencing is set in the controller but is **not** available in the model, which is where you have `total` defined. If you have a model which holds a collection of items. The other two answers have addressed the other errors in this code.

Answer (score 0):

<s>1) Your view is apparently looking for the `name` method, but you have defined the `total` method.</s> (question was edited to fix this.)

2) You have calculated a `summ` in the `total` method, but apparently don't `return` it from the method.

3) You are defining a method of the `Item` class, i.e. something that you can call upon an individual item; however, you would like to sum the prices of several items together.

Comment: I edited my code for items.total. And how to return summ? i am newbie))

Comment: I don't actually really know anything about RoR; I just know how to look at programs logically. :) You return a value with the `return` keyword (you should know the Ruby language before working with RoR, you know); but I don't know how much Ruby code you can embed in the html template... although I would try to do the summation there. A bit of Google searching suggests that Rails already provides a `sum` method for an array object, which is what `@items` presumably is.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Enumerable method `inject` method. You should probably compute this value in the controller and pass it to the view

controller

```
@summ = @items.inject(0) {|sum, item| sum + item.price }
```

view

```
<h1>Summ:<%= @summ %></h1>
```

Comment: I changed it but still have noMethodError. Can you write please the whole peace of code for model and for view.

Comment: So we can insert this into the template directly, yes? Something like `<h1>Summ:<%= @items.inject(0) {|sum, item| sum + item.price} %></h1>` ? Learning by doing here... :)

Comment: Thank you. But still have undefined method `+' for #<Item:0x000000023b51a8> http://pastie.org/1370977

Comment: You could, but it's best practice to have as little code in the view as possible. That is why I suggested putting the @summ calculation in the controller. and then reference @summ in the view.