# Calculating order totals in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to calculate totals in an orders model in Rails and having a little bit of trouble. The discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423739/cant-understand-how-to-sum-items-price-in-ror) helps, but doesn't quite apply to my case.

Basically, a user can chose products which are added to their order, then saved as order_products. I have the following models (only relevant fields are mentioned):

```
#products table has fields name, price
class Product 
end 

#orders table has field total
class Order
  has_many :order_products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_products
end

#orderproducts table has fields order_id, product_id, qty
class OrderProduct
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end
```

What is the best way to sum items to create an order total? Obviously you can't just pass in a hidden field on the order form right, as someone could manipulate that. I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
class Order
  has_many :order_products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_products
  before_save :calc_total

  def calc_total
    self.total = order_products.product.sum(&:price)
    #or should this be order_products.sum(&product.price) or similar?
  end 
end
```

But that doesn't look like the right syntax. Maybe I can't use the 'sum' function, and should just loop through the order_products and look up the price from the Product model? Surely this is a pretty common scenario - am I going about it the right way?

Also, given that product prices may change, is it best to also store the price of each product in the order products table, at the time of the order? In this case would I just add another before_save function in the OrderProduct model, looking up the current price from the Product model, multiply it by the qty and saving as a product_total value?

And lastly, what happens if a product is deleted, when there are order_products that reference it? Will this cause issues? Or am I ok if I cache the necessary product data in the order_products table at the time of order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working with the following, not sure if its the best way though

```
def calc_totals
  self.total = 0
  order_products.each do |op|
    self.total += op.product.price * op.qty
    op.item_price = op.product.price
    op.item_total = op.product.price * op.qty
  end
end
```